# Magento-Text given in Flat Rate Title is selectively displayed in frontend at central part of the checkout page

Tags: php, magento, checkout, rate, flat

I am using magento 1.8.1.0 and I am trying to make a purchase of products as a guest,not registered user.I am doing 2 trials:

First I buy a product that is relatively cheap and then I do the same thing with a more expensive product.When I do the checkout(with a low price purchase) and on the central part of the site under the title Shipping Methods,I can see the text that "shipping charges are customer's",and this is what I want,but when I am doing the same thing with more expensive products I cannot see the above text.I checked the things below:

1. if there is a shopping cart rule from the admin environment,that
   is responsible for this,but there isn't.
2. flushed the magento cache,neither that.
3. if there is another module enabled in

> `admin>System>Configuration>Sales>Shipping`

method,but there isn't.

With an inspect with chrome I found the relevant part of code in file

> frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/shipping_method/available.phtml

and is

```
<dt><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getCarrierName($code)) ?></dt>.
```

The relevant code in class at Available.php is

```
public function getCarrierName($carrierCode)
    {
        if ($name = Mage::getStoreConfig('carriers/'.$carrierCode.'/title')) {
            return $name;
        }
        return $carrierCode;
    }
```

The text "shipping charges are customer's" has been given in the Flat Rate module in magento backend.I don't understand why isn't the text shows up always in frontend ,no matter the price of the purchase i do,and shows only partially.What am i missing,thanks

Comment: You should try to be concise and to the point.

Comment: I want the text that i give in magento:admin>System>Configuration>Sales>Shipping Methods>Flat Rate>Title,to be shown in frontend.This actually happens but for some products added in shopping cart,and i expected to happen for all products that i have in shopping cart, either they cost 1 euro either 1000 euro

Comment: the above happen in content in frontend